# Detect change in google sheet and perform action- sheets API

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to create a python script with google sheets api to:
When I write a new name in the first row of a google sheet document, retrieve info from a database and pre-populate the next three rows with the info in the database (if that name is in the database) (know it sounds strange but it's not for my own use).
I thought about having a script running all of the time and whenever it detects that there's a change in the first row, retrieve the info from SQL and write it to the sheet.

I've read a lot of the official documentation, however, I don't find how I can detect those changes to perform the action. Thus, I would like to know how I could approach this (and if it's even possible or not).

I hope I've explained it well, if something is unclear, feel free to ask me. I would be really thankful if someone could help me!

Comment: I think in this scenario you would be better off with a Google App Script on the sheet itself...

Comment: Is it allowed to install the Google Drive for desktop in your computer that runs your python script? If there is no need to respond in real-time, you can check the update-time of the copy of your sheet on your computer and then do the things.

Comment: I need it to be in real time

Comment: @Samuel did you look into Apps Script triggers? Otherwise maybe you could use the [Drive.Files.watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/watch) method, and receive a notification when file was changed, then using the sheets API retrieve the value and do your logic. Still this seems more like a job where Apps Script would be good because you could use [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: @Aerials, thanks, I've already started doing it with app script triggers and I'm pretty happy with it.